# presentViewController-- Attempt to present __ on __ whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller

I'm attempting to do a `presentViewController` with an `UIImagePickerControl` in order to display a standard Camera Roll photo picker.  This works end-to-end in most of my app.  The place where it does not work is when I want to use the imagePicker inside an already presented `viewController`; the view to present the album is unable to be presented.

The basic idea is I'm trying to either access the `rootViewController` on the window object, or the app delegate's persisted `tabBarController` (which is the `rootViewController`); both as examples of top level items that are hopefully always present.  Just using "self" otherwise ends up as a partial view presenting it.

Is there a reliable way to `presentViewController` inside an already presentedView?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    // 1. attempt that works well elsewhere in app
    [((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).tabBarController presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

    // 2. this does nothing, no crash or action  (_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController)
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

    // 3. attempt off related internet suggestion, nothing happens
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }
    [topController presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `presentViewController` is meant as a modal presentation, I don't think it's possible to present a second modal at the same time in the same `UIWindow`. You could, however, add a new `UIWindow` and present it there.

```
originalWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
tempWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
tempWindow.rootViewController = controller;
[tempWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[controller presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You'll want to add something like this in your response to the image picker's return:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  // Process the result and then...
  [self cleanupWindow];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
  [self cleanupWindow];
}

- (void)cleanupWindow {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(madeKeyWindow:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:nil];
  [originalWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)madeKeyWindow:(NSNotification *)notification {
  [tempWindow removeFromSuperview];
  tempWindow = nil;
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:nil];
}
```